# Magento APC Multi Storefront

Tags: magento-1.9, apc

So I can see plenty of information about what to do with Magento and APC for single storefronts but how about multi stores?

I have 1 local.xml files that has 3 storefronts on that are on 3 different domains. In my local.xml I have the following:

```
<cache>
   <backend>apc</backend>
   <prefix>sitename_</prefix>
</cache>
```

Is this correct or should there be different prefixes for the different storefronts? I'm inclined to say that way I have done is correct but could anyone else confirm either way?

Comment: do not use APC or ZendOpcache for magento, just keep it for php, in magento use Redis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of this, https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/48017/361

If you still wanted to use APC as a cache store, then you don't need to define it per store view. Like the DB credentials, they are set globally, once.