# Magento 2 - Which cache are required to be installed on server for best performance in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish, redis, pagespeed

**Magento 2 best performance** which are the cache should be installed on the server for best performance of Magento 2 website in production mode?

Varnish/ Redis/ Memcache which one is best option to use together?

I have ubuntu server with LAMP installation as per Magento 2 requirement.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Best Answer @https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48003/magento-cache-confusion-about-varnish-redis-apc-memcache

Comment: is it suitable for magento 2 as well ?