# Magento 2 goes down with 100 concurrent users

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

Magento 2 goes down with 100 concurrent users and i am using 2 server(load balancing) with 32 GB RAM, 16 core CPU and 6 GB php memory.
what should i do for 1000 concurrent user.
Please suggest me magento 2 is capable or not ?

Comment: have you tried Varnish Cache?

Comment: NO I am using memcached

Comment: Check this out:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48003/magento-cache-confusion-about-varnish-redis-apc-memcache

Comment: @SaphalJha did you worked with 500+ concurrent users ?

Comment: No, but I had worked with 250+ users previously at the time of sell.

Comment: your contact number plz

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FUL:L PROCESSLIST; 
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @SURENDERSINGH Please view this customer Review   https://www.instagram.com/p/Br8q3rDHw80/    and get in touch by Skype.